# TV wall mount that rotates the tv 90 degrees

Tags: mount, tv, rotate

Where can i buy a tv wall mount that can rotate the tv 90 degrees (in the vertical plane) for storage?

Comment: Amazing that you got answers for that one, it's still off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

For all your TV-mounting related needs, the industry geek-gold-standard go-to website is [Monoprice](http://www.monoprice.com). you simply can't beat the awesome combination of price, quality, and service they offer.

You will be looking for a mount that has Tilt/Swivel functions, like [this one](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=108&cp_id=10828&cs_id=1082806&p_id=3725&seq=1&format=2).

[image]

EDIT: Forgot you want to ROTATE the TV 90 degrees - it seems Monoprice do not have something like that in stock (tilt/swivel is not rotation).

You could try [this mount from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WEHJGC) instead - pricy though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a wall mount for an LCD or flatscreen TV, [this website](http://www.ergoindemand.com/lcd_wall_mounts.htm) has a pretty good selection. If the mount can rotate 90 degrees it'll be listed in the specification (many can). When looking for a mount, you need only verify that a) your TV has a VESA-compliant mounting bracket (most do) and b) that the wall mount can support the weight of the TV (and as always, make sure you have a stud in the wall to support the weight!). As long as your TV has the VESA mounting bracket, then all you're looking for is a "VESA wall mount", a search for which google returns numerous results both from online retailers and brick-and-mortar stores.